# Javascript - Change Button function once I click it

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button and 3 functions.
change each funtion once I click it 
Please Help me.

Comment: where is the button?

Comment: <button id ="btn_big" value = "btn_1"/>

Comment: You have those functions, or you want to have them?

Comment: i want to have them.

Comment: i mean did you say `I have a button and 3 functions` put your tired somethings People are downvoting cause you don't show any effort to do it by yourself. Add some code you have tried ,and you can go learn java script for please be refer the  https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
i dont understand your question, i think you mean like this one button
```

try it  and use `document.getElementById`

```html
<button id="btn" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML = 'Hey There'">Try it</button>
```

Comment: i have 1 buttons named "btn_big" and 3 function. when i click first it change to second function and if i click it again it change to last function.

Comment: `please put the your code part, we can easy to fix this issue` and use` code snippet` put in your code it

Comment: i don't know how to javascript

Comment: no no , i mean did you say `I have a button and 3 functions ` put your tired somethings People are downvoting cause you don't show any effort to do it by yourself. Add some code you have tried ,and you can go learn java script for please be refer the  https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Pass the `this` with in a function .It will target the same clicked button element

```js
function change(that){
that.value="changed"
that.innerHTML="changed" //for inner html change
console.log(that.outerHTML)
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" type="button" onclick="change()">click</button>
```

For **single** line code

```html
    <button id="btn" type="button" onclick="this.innerHTML='changed'">click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" onclick="a()">click</button>
```

javascript

```
var a = (function() {
    var clicked = 0;
    return function() {
        clicked++;
        if (clicked == 1) f1(); // improve this part 
        if (clicked == 2) f2();
        if (clicked == 3) f3();
    }

})()

function f1() {
    alert(1)
}

function f2() {
    alert(2)
}

function f3() {
    alert(3)
}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gm7xn5mq/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function change(that){
      that.value="Changed"
      that.innerHTML="Changed"
}

<button id="btn" type="button" onclick="change(this)">click</button


      or


<button id="btn" type="button" onclick = "this.innerHTML = 'Changed'" > click </button>
```

or

```
<button id="btn" type="button" onclick = "document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML = 'Changed' "> Try it </button>
```